# Set button in custom view (canvas)

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, draw

I would like to set up a button that would allow me to move to another activity while I finished drawing my painting.

The question is I don't know how to set up this button in the view class because it doesn't listen to any listeners.

Answer (score 0):

In your drawing view, define your interface

```
public class MyDrawingView extends View
{
    protected MyPaintingListener m_paintingListener;     

    public interface MyPaintingListener 
    {
        // you can define any parameter as per your requirement
        public void paintingEnded();
    }

    public void onCreateView()
    {
        // Create your view
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        // Draw your painting
        // then
        if(m_paintingListener != null)
            m_paintingListener.paintingEnded();
    }

    public void setListener(MyPaintingListener p_listener)
    {
        m_paintingListener = p_listener;
    }
}
```

In your current Fragment or Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements MyDrawingView.MyPaintingListener
{
    protected MyDrawingView m_drawingView;

    public void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // In this method or another, create your drawingView 
        m_drawingView = new MyDrawingView();
        m_drawingView.setListener(this);
        m_drawingView.paint();
    }


    @Override
    public void paintingEnded()
    {
        // Set up your button;
    }
}
```